# Loop en un timer VB.net

Tags: vb.net

tengo una pregunta, como se genera un loop de un timer que en cada segundo este evaluando una funcion, Por Ejemplo:

```
for i as integer =0 to 10 ('segundos por ejemplo)
 if talcosa = 1 then
  ()do_something
next i
```

es solo para ejemplificar pero no logro hacer que cada segundo se evalue algo

Comment: El de windows Forms (el que se agrega al formulario)? O el timer de .net??

Comment: Declara un [Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=net-6.0) con 1000 milisegundos de retraso (1 segundo convertido) y pones ese cacho de codigo en el evento que genera el timer cada intervalo de tiempo que tu le has dicho y listo